# Mid vol from bid/ask vols for equity options

Tags: implied-volatility

Given an arbitrary bid IV and ask IV is it possible to compute a mid IV in a model agnostic fashion? Is there anything else aside averaging the bid and ask vols or interpolation between bid/ask ivs and prices? Having the mid IV be arbitrage-free is not a concern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Averaging the bid/ask volatilities would be the only "model-free" way to do it.

Indeed, recalling that:
$$ f^{-1}( f(x) ) = x $$
applying the chain rule of standard calculus gives
$$ (f^{-1})'(y) = 1/f'(f^{-1}(y)) $$

Defining $f$ as the function which maps a Black-Scholes volatility to the European vanilla price (all other pricing parameters held constant)
$$ f: \sigma \to V(\sigma,\cdot) $$
its inverse $f^{-1}$ becomes the function which outputs the implied volatility from an input price.

From an order 1 Taylor expansion of $f^{1}$
$$ (f^{-1})'(y) = (f^{-1})'(y_0) + 1/f'(f^{-1}(y_0))(y-y_0) + o(y) $$
of the bid/ask implied volatilities ($y\in \{C_{bid},C_{ask}\}$) around the mid level ($y_0=C_{mid}$) would get you
\begin{align}
\sigma_{bid} &= \sigma_{mid} + 1/\nu_{mid}(C_{bid}-C_{mid}) \\
\sigma_{ask} &= \sigma_{mid} + 1/\nu_{mid}(C_{ask}-C_{mid}) 
\end{align}
where $\nu_{mid}$ denotes the contract's Vega (using the mid implied vol in input). Letting the bid/ask spread
$$ \delta := C_{ask}-C_{bid} $$
and adding the two equations together would then indeed yield
$$\sigma_{mid} = 1/2(\sigma_{bid}+\sigma_{ask})$$

Basically what this says is as long as $f$ is linear in the volatility, the rule of thumb is exact (since $f^{-1}$ will be too, assuming it exists).

Now, as soon as you have material convexity (i.e. far from the money), using an order 2 expansion rather than an order 1 expansion, you'll see that the Volga at $\sigma_{mid}$ appears thereby yielding a non-linear "fixed point" problem can only be solved assuming a model.

Comment: Just a quick follow up question, in the case where the bid iv isn't computable or is just 0, would the averaging still make sense?

Comment: If you look at a single option, it might make sense, as you are simply saying you would be willing to buy the option very cheap (only its intrinsic value, no time value). But if you have options with other strikes in your books with the same maturity be careful the resulting mid vol does not create static arbitrage opportunities (fly arb, vertical arb).